# How to make non-stopping loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, infinite-loop

I have an image inside a div and I want it to change every 2 seconds.

```
var i = 0, images = [];

images[0] = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/27/20/29/landscape-403165_960_720.jpg";
images[1] = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/36478/amazing";

function repeat() {
    $(".exch img").attr("src", images[i]);
    i = i + 1;
}
setInterval(repeat, 2000);
```

This code works fine for changing pics but when it reaches to the last image, it stops. The point is that I want the loop to start over again and repeat itself for many times.

I also want the `src` for `images[0]` to be the image src in my local disk `image/01.jpg`, not `http://wwww.example.com/01.jpg`.

How do I do that?

Comment: you can use `setInterval`

Comment: My guess is that your `repeat()` function is continuing to run, but using invalid values of your index `i`. Instead of `i = i + 1;` you should say `i = (i + 1) % images.length;` That will cause the index to start over at the beginning of your images array. Sorry I can't advise you on your other question--I would need to know more about the environment you're running in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already running it in the infinite loop using `setInterval` but the issue here is there are no more images in the `images` array. There are only two images in `images` array and `setInterval` keeps on incrementing `i` value but there are no 3rd or 4th images.

You need reset `i` value to `0` after reaching the last `images` array... so that `setInterval` will run non-stop and keep showing the repeated images.

```
var i = 0,
    images = [];
images[0] = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/27/20/29/landscape403165_960_720.jpg";
images[1] = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/36478/amazing";
function repeat() {
    if(i > images.length - 1) i = 0;
    $(".exch img").attr("src", images[i]);
    i = i + 1;
    console.log(i);
}
setInterval(repeat, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

At code at Question `i` increments to a value greater than `images` array `.length` at `i = i + 1;`

You can use [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator `%`  to either set `i` to `0` or `1` within `repeat` function

```
function repeat() {
  $(".exch img").attr("src", images[i]);
  i = ++i % images.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your var i is increase over your images[] length

try do this `$(".exch img").attr("src", images[i%images.length]);`

second question:

if you are running Html on server (like express, ror...)

I think you can't include img from local path,

you need to put your image on public route.